# Go: reference types as arguments

Tags: parameters, go, reference

Certain types in Go are reference types: maps, slices, channels, functions, and methods.

Sometimes you need to use pointers to references. For example,

```
type Stack []interface{}
func (stack *Stack) Push(x interface{}) { 
    *stack = append(*stack, x)
}
```

You need it because all arguments are passed by copying the value, and `append()` might need to reallocate memory in the slice's capacity is not big enough. I get that.

**First question.** How about `map` types? If I have a custom type based on a `map`, should I better *always* pass a pointer to it if some key:value insertions or deletions are expected?

**Second question.** What about other reference types? `Channel`, for example. I can imagine a situation where I build a custom type based on a channel to implement some custom pre-processing for the values being passed to a channel. Pointers needed here too?

Sorry if this is basic as heck, but I really want to get a good grasp of the subject.

Comment: You're confusing the slice descriptor with the underlying array. There are no reference types in Go. You have values, you have pointers. A pointer is a 'reference'. And I don't know what your code sample is doing but  that certainly isn't necessary. A worthwhile read http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: no, that requires a pointer, because an append may allocate a new array, changing the internal data pointer, as well and the len and cap values. http://play.golang.org/p/Cm8AQXpK5J

Comment: @JimB yeah I noticed that while tinkering with it in playground. That necessity is caused by the silly design though. Just define the method with a receiver and return type of `Stack` and do `myStack = myStack.Push(x)`. Or better yet, define none of this because it is all just a waste of your systems RAM. Like the only reason it acts that way is because append is made to handle the slice descriptor as a value, returning a new one after the action completes. Then he does something inconsistent in making his type which is nothing more than a slice chain the method using a pointer.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: there's perfectly good reasons to use custom types like this. Look at `container/heap`in the stdlib for example, or the `sort` package (which shows where you *don't* need pointers). There's many more examples of just using custom types like this throughout the stdlib, including map and func types too.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal By the way, the example is from http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Go-Creating-Applications-Developers/dp/0321774639

Comment: @JimB True, not saying custom types are useless, just the particular example. However, if you're going make a custom type which is nothing more than a slice I would keep things consistent and define the methods for that type with a value receiver, not a pointer, just saying.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: though it's named "stack",  this example is basically taken directly from the heap package, which *requires* a pointer receiver to fulfill heap.Interface.

Comment: @JimB that's fine, you're not going to convince me it's a good design by proving that someone at Google was stupid enough to put it in the standard library. All that abstraction does is leak and slow down application performance.

Comment: There are no reference types in Go. E.g. a slice is not a reference type and a chanel also is not a reference type. The closest type in Go to resemble reference types are maps. Stop using "reference type" really helps: There are no.

Comment: @Volker The first line was a citation from the book I mentioned earlier in the comments, which happens to be my first "formal" source of information about the language, so I stick to the terminology used there. The Go Specification indeed mentions Boolean types, Numeric types, String types, Array types, Slice types, Struct types, Pointer types, Function types, Interface types, Map types and Channel types.

Comment: Yeah that goes beyond this question or anything but the use of 'reference types' as if they're any different than any other value has become a big pet peeve of mine. In every language everything is a value, period. That value could be a memory address, but it is fundamentally the same as any other value even if I can 'dereference' it to access some other value. It doesn't make it any less of a value, just one which that operation is defined for. No one acts like ints are special because `+` is defined for them but not other types...

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Could you please take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65717235/how-reference-types-are-called-in-go-in-general ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The rules are fairly easy when you think of everything as a value, where some values contain pointers internally.

- **slices**: Use a pointer when you may need to modify the length or capacity, which changes the value of the slice.
- **maps**: Don't use a pointer, since the map value doesn't change with modifications.
- **functions and methods**: Don't use a pointer, the same effect is had through function values.
- **chan**: Don't use a pointer.

There are of course exceptions, like if you want to be able to swap out a map entirely you would need to use pointer to do so, but these are rare cases.

Comment: You do not necessarily have to synchronise modifications to pointers to chans. If the modifications happen only by a single goroutine, synchronisation is not needed (just like with all pointers).

Comment: @rightfold: well, nothing needs to be synchronized if there's only access in one goroutine, but even if the value is only *modified* in a single goroutine, unsynchronized concurrent reads of that value are still a race condition. Though, that condition is the same as a shared chan value in the same scope. I'll remove the phrasing as it's probably more confusing than helpful.

Answer (score 7):

There isn't really a dichotomy between "value types" and "reference types". "Reference type" is just used to describe a value type whose "value" consists wholly of a single pointer.

This is true for map and channel types, which are basically pointer types to an internal structure. But this is not completely true for slices, because a slice is a composite type (basically a struct), consisting of two integer values (length & capacity) and a pointer (to the elements). So it is a "reference type" with respect to the elements, which are accessed through the pointer, but it is a "value type" with respect to the length and capacity.

Appending to a slice operates on its length and potentially capacity, so it needs to change the "value" of the slice, whereas assigning to elements in place just uses the pointer, and thus does not need to change the "value" of the slice. You might also need to change the "value" of a slice if you want it to change the pointer to point to the same as another slice (which you would do by assigning to the slice).

It's similar for the "reference types", maps and channels. Changing the "contents" of the map or channel (which is in the stuff pointed to by the pointer) doesn't require changing the "value" of the map or channel. But if you wanted to change the pointer to point to a different underlying map or channel, then you would change the "value" of the map or channel variable.

Comment: While it is a good answer, it should not begin with "There isn't really a dichotomy between "value types" and "reference types"". There _is_ a _difference_ between value types such as structs that involve copying contents when passed as function parameter and types such as maps, for example, which don't involve copying contents of a map that is passed as function parameter. Whether or not "difference" is sufficiently weaker than "dichotomy" that allows to state "absence of dichotomy" while there's clearly "presence of difference" is debatable and confusing.