# Is there a general name for Go types with "reference semantics" such as map, slice and channel?

Tags: go

According to responses and comments in [Go: reference types as arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31170368/go-reference-types-as-arguments) Go does not seem to have types that are "officially" called "reference types".

Yet, there are some types that actually hold pointers to the underlying data which allows to efficiently pass values of these types as function arguments without taking pointer to them. When such value is passed as a function argument, there is no (or very little as with slices) copying of the underlying data so that there is no (or very little) efficiency gain if a programmer takes the pointer to the type and passes this pointer as the function argument instead of the value.

Such types are **slices**, **maps**, and **channels** according to [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31171339/484050).

The official Effective Go document [describes Slices](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#slices) as:

> Slices hold references to an underlying array, and if you assign one slice to another, both refer to the same array. If a function takes a slice argument, changes it makes to the elements of the slice will be visible to the caller, analogous to passing a pointer to the underlying array.

[Maps](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#maps) as:

> Like slices, maps hold references to an underlying data structure. If you pass a map to a function that changes the contents of the map, the changes will be visible in the caller.

and [Channels](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels) as:

> Like maps, channels are allocated with make, and the resulting value acts as a reference to an underlying data structure.

Documentation seems to avoid using the term "reference types" with regards to these types for whatever reason but still mentions the word "reference" in each case.

What also makes these types special is that one can assign `nil` to a value of this type similar to pointer types ([doc](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability)):

> A value `x` is assignable to a variable of type `T` ("`x` is assignable to `T`") if one of the following conditions applies:
> ...
>
> - `x` is the predeclared identifier `nil` and `T` is a pointer, function, slice, map, channel, or interface type.

In the daily programmer's practice it **is important** to know, clearly differentiate and clearly communicate types or data structures that when passed around as function parameters share the underlying data versus the ones that don't share (but copy) the underlying data.

Being able to refer to **slices**, **maps**, and **channels** as a single group in conversation with other, especially junior, programmers is a big advantage to clear communication helping to ensure data safety in programs and identify/prevent hazards connected to mutating the shared sate.

How can this group of types be called in general?

Comment: The "whatever reason" is this: https://dave.cheney.net/2017/04/29/there-is-no-pass-by-reference-in-go

Comment: But as you wrote, "there are some types that actually hold pointers". These types are still equivalent to C structs.

Comment: Go's only reference types are pointers. Slices, maps, and channels being described as "holding" or "acting as" a reference just refer to them being or containing pointers in the underlying type definition.

Comment: https://github.com/go101/go101/wiki/About-the-terminology-%22reference-type%22-in-Go sheds a light on the history of this "terminology" topic

Answer (score 1):

> How can this [slices, maps, functions and methods, and channels] group of types be called in general?

The question is illformed as methods are not types in Go and function types are, well just functions and do not fit into the discussion about "references".
Assuming you want to talk about slices, maps, closures and buffered channels:

These are called "slices, maps, closures and buffered channels" and there probably is no need to have a name for these 4: They have not much in common.

The following four types exhibit reference semantics: slices, maps, closures and buffered channels. (Unbuffered channels don't).

- A slice is a value type which presents a view into the backing array. It has thus reference semantics in regard to the values stored in the backing array.
- A map is a map and has reference semantics in regard to the values stored in the map. (This one is the closest to a reference type.)
- Function closers are closures and are complicated and talking about them with juniors in the light of value ownership probably is not helpful).
- A buffered channel shows reference semantics in regard to buffered values.

There is no need for a complicated term (unless you work in academics and classifying, separating and taxonomizing is your living.)

Comment: This answer is basically correct, although "types exhibit reference semantics" probably means different things to different people. If you compare Go to a language like C# which differentiates between reference and value types, there is certainly a distinction which is not visible from the syntax. Parameters are always passed by value in Go or C or C#, but adding a value to a `map` inside a function will mutate the original object (even though the map was passed by value), while calling a method on a custom struct inside the method might mutate the struct, but won't affect the outside world.

Comment: 1) There was no request for complicated term. As it stands out from the answer, your proposed definition is "types with reference semantics". Is this correct? 2) There's no value to label the question as "nonsensical" based on functions/methods not fitting in the group. This was taken from linked answer. Please comment there and help improve it. I removed the mention from the question. 3) The answer gives an impression that the question is worthless; surprising that it was still answered. Maybe, if you remove the emotional context, the answer will be more valuable?

Comment: @Mike 1) No. The problem with "types with reference semantics" is that lots of struct types also show reference semantics if they include pointer fields which leads to 3) Yes, I think it is not beneficial to invent a term or taxonomy here. The amount of types in Go is pretty small and they simply do not fall into lots of natural classes and you have to learn the rules. You have to understand what pointer types are and which rules apply (e.g. that you cannot define methods on pointer types). In the same sense you just have to learn what a slice is:

Comment: @Mike A slice is view into a backing array. Same for buffered channels. Or function closures. You have to understand _closures_ and that functions are first class types in Go. The fact that copying a function closure or a buffered channel doesn't copy what is closed over or buffered in is pretty natural and understanding that doesn't need a made up term. For 2) I changed the answer slightly.

Comment: Thanks for helpful improvements. The point of my question is that some types can present hazards in situations when the underlying shared state is mutated. When dealing with pointers the situation is pretty clear because the pointer is _explicit_ opt-in for shared state. There's no hazard when dealing with "true" value types because values are copied and there's no shared state. And there's a third category which is subject of my question, types that are not _explicitly_ pointers but can present hazards because they effectively refer to a state that gets shared when values are passed around.

Comment: @Mikes "When dealing with pointers the situation is pretty clear because the pointer is explicit opt-in for shared state." Note that pointers fields in a struct may be unexported and this invisible for the caller. You seem to try to create a dichotomy which is not real.

Comment: Yes, structs are potentially hazardous. But, as far as pointers are concerned, a programmer who has the source code can trace where pointers are involved. Slices, maps, channels and closures are different in this aspect because their implementation is typically not part of application logic which typical programmer is concerned about. Not all structs present potential hazard because not all have inner pointers. Yet, every map is potentially hazardous. Whether or not dichotomy is valid, there seems no disagreement that slices, maps, etc. are (1) built-in and (2) require special understanding.

Comment: To close on this topic: if I would include pointers in the original question, the "taxonomy" might have been more complete and would not put a special emphasis on bult-ins (map, slice, channel, closure). This would look less like questioning golang design decisions and may not have cause down vote and cast to close the question.

Comment: Buffered and unbuffered channels are no different in terms of reference semantics. If you pass a channel to a function, it's the same channel as the caller had, not a copy; there is never any need to pass a pointer to a channel. Channels, buffered or not, exhibit reference semantics.

Comment: @Adrian: he's referring to the values within the buffered channel, like a slice in that sense. In the case of a channel though it should be thought of as a pointer and nothing more (since like a map, it's actually just a pointer). Since a channel is used as a pointer value, I agree the mention of buffered channels (which is still technically correct because the buffer is referenced by a pointer in the `hchan.buf` field) is not useful here.

Comment: @Adrian A buffered channel can act as a kind of container: You can fill in data and get the data out later on. Like a map. And like a copy of a map doesn't copy the contained values a copy of a channel doesn't copy the values "contained". With the difference that an unbuffered channel cannot hold or store anything and cannot act as a container. So for unbuffered channels it doesn't matter whether copies of the values they contain are made or not during copying the container: They never contain values.

Comment: It matters in that if you pass a channel value to a function, that function will have *the same channel*, not a copy. It's still reference semantics; it doesn't matter if it's "storing" values or not. If it were not reference semantics, you'd have to pass a pointer to the channel for it to work as expected.

Comment: @Adrian I agree with you on a technically level. But an unbuffered channel is much less a "thing" (or a value) than any other type. Like a wormhole in spacetime it is not an existing "thing" but a topological property of the spacetime an unbuffered channel is not a "real value" but just a synchronisation point where two parties who decide to send and receive from the channel exchange a value. In that sense an unbuffered channel just modifies the possible set of Happens-Before graphs accessible to your code; just like a wormhole increases the set of possible spacetime curves.

Comment: (I know, it's more complicated as close on an unbuffered channel is some kind of broadcast). While thinking of a buffered channel as a collection of things buffered is a fine mental image (and such buffers clearly show reference semantics) a unbuffered channel can be imagined as even _less_ than a value (again technically you are correct). With just one sender an one receiver it is a topological property of your HB graph (with select or multiple sender/receivers, the set of potential HB graphs).

Comment: Both buffered and unbuffered channels can have more than one receiver and more than one sender communicating through them. You can pass channel value in the code creating another possible entrance or exit to the same wormhole. In the presence of multiple entrances/exits, what/where enters or exits is decided randomly according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/31539859/484050